# fglob() ошибка поиска файлов рекурсивно по маске в выбранной директории

Tags: файлы, golang, рекурсия

Пытаюсь найти файлы в выбранной директории РЕКУРСИВНО, с расширением `.txt`, код рекурсивной фукнции:

```
func fglob(dir string, ext string) ([]string, error) {
    var files = []string{}
    var err = filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if filepath.Ext(path) == ext {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })

    return files, err
}

fglob("C:/files", ".txt");
```

Основной код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    var files []string
    var err error

    files, err = fglob(
        "C:/files/folder",
        fmt.Sprintf("%s",
            ".txt",
        ),
    )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        from, err := os.Open(
            fmt.Sprintf("%s",
                file,
            ),
        )
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer from.Close()

        fileStat, err := from.Stat()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if fileStat.Size() < 1 {
            continue
        } else if fileStat.Size() > 5000 {
            continue
        }

        to, err := os.OpenFile("c:/files/folder/f2/"+file, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        defer to.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(to, from)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

    }

}

func fglob(dir string, ext string) ([]string, error) {
    var files = []string{}
    var err = filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if filepath.Ext(path) == ext {
            files = append(files, path)
        }
        return nil
    })

    return files, err
}
```

Но мне пишет `open C:\files\folder\f2/C:\files\folder\retr.txt: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` потому что название директорий и файлов соединяет воедино. Мне нужно искать в конкретных директориях, а не в текущей.

Comment: В приведённом коде ошибок не видно. Покажите настоящий код.

Comment: @Ainar-G добавил.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте [документацию](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#WalkFunc) внимательно!

> (…) The path argument contains the argument to Walk as a prefix; that is, if Walk is called with "dir", which is a directory containing the file "a", the walk function will be called with argument "dir/a". (…)

Если вам нужно базовое имя файла, используйте `filepath.Base`:

```golang
files = append(files, filepath.Base(path))
```

Если вам нужно имя относительно директории, переименуйте аргумент `fglob` из `dir` в напрмер `basedir` и используйте `filepath.Rel`:

```golang
relpath, err := filepath.Rel(basedir, path)
// Check err.
files = append(files, relpath)
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста дать полный ответ с полным кодом? Я просто не пойму что и как задействовать, какие аргументы ПЕРЕДАТЬ в функцию, абсолютный/базовый/относительный путь ...